# Compute the Adjoint of a operator $T_f$

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, adjoint-operators

If $f\in C[0,1]$ let $T_f(g)=fg$ for $g\in L_2[0,1]$. Show that $T_f$ is continuous, linear and $(T_f)^\ast=T_{\overline{f}}$.

I showed that $T_f$ is linear and continuous. My question is in the proof of $(T_f)^\ast=T_{\overline{f}}$.

My work:

From the unicity of Adjoint of $T_f$ I need show that for all $g,h\in L_2[0,1]$ and $f\in C[0,1]$ $$\langle T_f(g), h\rangle=\langle g, \overline{f}h\rangle$$ But
$$\langle g, T_{\overline{f}}(h)\rangle=\langle g, \overline{f}h\rangle=f\langle g, h\rangle=\langle fg, h\rangle=\langle T_f(g), h\rangle$$

My proof is correct?

My Doubt is:

I can treat $f$ as a scalar and take it out of the inner product like I did before?

Comment: You can't treat $f$ as a scalar. However, you can manipulate how $f$ interacts with the inner product by writing out the actual $L^2$ inner product: $\langle g, h \rangle = \int g(x) h(x) \, dx$.

Comment: @Christhopher A. Wong  $ \langle g, h \rangle = \int_0^1g(x) h(x) \, dx$?

Comment: My mistake; I meant $\langle g, h \rangle = \int_0^1 g(x) \overline{h(x)} \, dx$.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot treat $f$ as a scalar.

$\langle T_f g, h \rangle= \int fg\overline {h} =\int g \overline {T_f^{*} h}$ for all $g \in L^{2}$. This implies that $f\overline h=\overline {T_f^{*} h}$ almost everywhere. This is same thing as $T_f^{*} h=h\overline f=T_{\overline f} h$. So $T_f^{*} =T_{\overline f} $.

I have used two facts:

1. If $F_1$ and $F_2 \in L^{2}$ then $F_1F_2 \in L^{1}$.
2. If $G_1, G_2 \in L^{1}$ and $\int g G_1=\int gG_2$ for all $g \in C[0,1]$ then $G_1=G_2$ almost everywhere.